# Display image when list contains specific string

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and i want a widget to display an image of LED when last element of the list contain `'LED:on'`. The element is from arduino thru hc05.

```
List<String> led = ['LED:on', 'LED:off', 'LED:on'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
List<String> led = ['LED:on', 'LED:off', 'LED:on'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
      children: [
        if (led.last.contains('LED:on'))  
           Image.network('https://eample.com.png')
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can know if the last element of the array contains 'LED:on' string with

```
led.last.contains('LED:on'), //It returns bool.
```

Use the Visibility widget which controls whether the given child is visible or not based on the bool value passed on the visible parameter.

Here is the complete code.

```
Visibility(
      visible: led.last.contains('LED:on'),
      child: Image.network('https://yourimageurl.com'), // Use Image.asset() for local image
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also.

```
List<String> led = ['LED:on', 'LED:off'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
      children: [
    if (led.last.contains('LED:on')) ...  
           [Image.network('https://eample.com.png')],
  
     if (led.last.contains('LED:off')) ...  
           [Image.network('https://eample2.com.png')],
      ],
    ));
  }
```